# String change not being caught by if?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, if-statement

I've got this code, a Breadth-first search for a AI problem that is funcionally working, I'm now trying to place a global String  that will change in accord to the actual "state" of the code, since it's a AI problem there's a lot of them
here's part of the code (the part that's of interest to us)

```py
import math

#______________________________________________________________________________
# Missionaries and Cannibals Problem
printestado = 'teste'
class Estado():
    global printestado
    def __init__(self, canibal_esq, missio_esq, barco, canibal_dir, missio_dir):
        self.canibal_esq = canibal_esq
        self.missio_esq = missio_esq
        self.barco = barco
        self.canibal_dir = canibal_dir
        self.missio_dir = missio_dir
        self.vizinho = None

    def objetivo_final(self):
        if self.canibal_esq == 0 and self.missio_esq == 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def eh_valido(self):
        if self.missio_esq >= 0 and self.missio_dir >= 0 \
                   and self.canibal_esq >= 0 and self.canibal_dir >= 0 \
                   and (self.missio_esq == 0 or self.missio_esq >= self.canibal_esq) \
                   and (self.missio_dir == 0 or self.missio_dir >= self.canibal_dir):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.canibal_esq == other.canibal_esq and self.missio_esq == other.missio_esq \
                   and self.barco == other.barco and self.canibal_dir == other.canibal_dir \
                   and self.missio_dir == other.missio_dir

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.canibal_esq, self.missio_esq, self.barco, self.canibal_dir, self.missio_dir))

def successors(estado_atual):
    global printestado
    children = [];
    if estado_atual.barco == 'esquerda':
        novo_estado = Estado(estado_atual.canibal_esq, estado_atual.missio_esq - 2, 'direita',
                                  estado_atual.canibal_dir, estado_atual.missio_dir + 2)
        printestado = 'test01'
        ## Dois missionários cruzam da esquerda pra direita
        if novo_estado.eh_valido():
            novo_estado.vizinho = estado_atual
            children.append(novo_estado)
        novo_estado = Estado(estado_atual.canibal_esq - 2, estado_atual.missio_esq, 'direita',
                                  estado_atual.canibal_dir + 2, estado_atual.missio_dir)
        printestado = 'test02'
        ## Dois canibais cruzam da esquerda pra direita
        if novo_estado.eh_valido():
            novo_estado.vizinho = estado_atual
            children.append(novo_estado)
        novo_estado = Estado(estado_atual.canibal_esq - 1, estado_atual.missio_esq - 1, 'direita',
                                  estado_atual.canibal_dir + 1, estado_atual.missio_dir + 1)
        printestado = 'test03'
        ## Um missionário e um canibal cruzam da esquerda pra direita
        if novo_estado.eh_valido():
            novo_estado.vizinho = estado_atual
            children.append(novo_estado)
        novo_estado = Estado(estado_atual.canibal_esq, estado_atual.missio_esq - 1, 'direita',
                                  estado_atual.canibal_dir, estado_atual.missio_dir + 1)
        printestado = 'test04'
        ## Um missionário cruza da esquerda pra direita
        if novo_estado.eh_valido():
            novo_estado.vizinho = estado_atual
            children.append(novo_estado)
        novo_estado = Estado(estado_atual.canibal_esq - 1, estado_atual.missio_esq, 'direita',
                                  estado_atual.canibal_dir + 1, estado_atual.missio_dir)
        printestado = 'test05'
        ## Um canibal cruza da esquerda pra direita
        if novo_estado.eh_valido():
            novo_estado.vizinho = estado_atual
            children.append(novo_estado)
    else:
        novo_estado = Estado(estado_atual.canibal_esq, estado_atual.missio_esq + 2, 'esquerda',
                                  estado_atual.canibal_dir, estado_atual.missio_dir - 2)
        printestado = 'test06'
        ## Dois missionários cruzam da direita pra esquerda
        if novo_estado.eh_valido():
            novo_estado.vizinho = estado_atual
            children.append(novo_estado)
        novo_estado = Estado(estado_atual.canibal_esq + 2, estado_atual.missio_esq, 'esquerda',
                                  estado_atual.canibal_dir - 2, estado_atual.missio_dir)
        printestado = 'test07'
        ## Dois canibais cruzam da direita pra esquerda
        if novo_estado.eh_valido():
            novo_estado.vizinho = estado_atual
            children.append(novo_estado)
        novo_estado = Estado(estado_atual.canibal_esq + 1, estado_atual.missio_esq + 1, 'esquerda',
                                  estado_atual.canibal_dir - 1, estado_atual.missio_dir - 1)
        printestado = 'test08'
        ## Um missionário e um canibal cruzam da direita pra esquerda
        if novo_estado.eh_valido():
            novo_estado.vizinho = estado_atual
            children.append(novo_estado)
        novo_estado = Estado(estado_atual.canibal_esq, estado_atual.missio_esq + 1, 'esquerda',
                                  estado_atual.canibal_dir, estado_atual.missio_dir - 1)
        printestado = 'test09'
        ## Um missionário cruza da direita pra esquerda
        if novo_estado.eh_valido():
            novo_estado.vizinho = estado_atual
            children.append(novo_estado)
        novo_estado = Estado(estado_atual.canibal_esq + 1, estado_atual.missio_esq, 'esquerda',
                                  estado_atual.canibal_dir - 1, estado_atual.missio_dir)
        printestado = 'test10'
        ## Um canibal cruza da direita pra esquerda
        if novo_estado.eh_valido():
            novo_estado.vizinho = estado_atual
            children.append(novo_estado)
    return children

def Busca_em_largura():
    estado_inicial = Estado(3,3,'esquerda',0,0)
    if estado_inicial.objetivo_final():
        return estado_inicial
    nao_explorados = list()
    explorados = set()
    nao_explorados.append(estado_inicial)
    while nao_explorados:
        estado = nao_explorados.pop(0)
        if estado.objetivo_final():
            return estado
        explorados.add(estado)
        children = successors(estado)
        for child in children:
            if (child not in explorados) or (child not in nao_explorados):
                nao_explorados.append(child)
    return None

def imprime_solucao(solucao):
        caminho = []
        caminho.append(solucao)
        vizinho = solucao.vizinho
        while vizinho:
            caminho.append(vizinho)
            vizinho = vizinho.vizinho

        for t in range(len(caminho)):
            estado = caminho[len(caminho) - t - 1]
            print("\nCalculando: ")
            print ("(" + str(estado.canibal_esq) + "," + str(estado.missio_esq) \
                              + "," + estado.barco + "," + str(estado.canibal_dir) + "," + \
                              str(estado.missio_dir) + ")")
            print(printestado)
      



def main():
    solucao = Busca_em_largura()
    print ("Problema dos missionários e canibais: \n")
    print ("Trabalho feito por ")
    print ("Aderbal Calmeto ")
    print ("Guilherme Paiva")
    print ("Legenda: (Canibais à esquerda , Missionários à esquerda")
    print ("Posição do Barco, Canibais à direita , Missionários à direita) \n\n")
    imprime_solucao(solucao)

# if called from the command line, call main()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

As I said, the code is working perfectly, the novo_estado.eh_valido() function returns TRUE of FALSE depending on the situation and is being changed over 12 different states during the code, but when I try to print (printestado) it's always returned to me "test10" even that (I think that) the 10th "test" is not even being accessed during the code execution, what makes me think that the "printestado" changes are maybe outside the ifs

Anyone have any idea of what I'm missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

In the code, there is one `if estado_atual.barco == 'esquerda':` statement, which if it returns TRUE, will change the `printestado` to test5. Else, it will set the variable to test10. So, the function `novo_estado.eh_valido()` doesnt appear to have impact on the variable. Perhaps you want to run only one function, they should be within `if/else` statement and the variable updates also within these statements... Something like this.

```
    if estado_atual.barco == 'esquerda':
        novo_estado = Estado(estado_atual.canibal_esq, estado_atual.missio_esq - 2, 'direita',
                                  estado_atual.canibal_dir, estado_atual.missio_dir + 2)
        printestado = 'test01'
        ## Dois missionários cruzam da esquerda pra direita
        if novo_estado.eh_valido():
            novo_estado.vizinho = estado_atual
            children.append(novo_estado)
            novo_estado = Estado(estado_atual.canibal_esq - 2, estado_atual.missio_esq, 'direita',
                                  estado_atual.canibal_dir + 2, estado_atual.missio_dir)
            printestado = 'test02'
        ## Dois canibais cruzam da esquerda pra direita
        elif novo_estado.eh_valido():
            novo_estado.vizinho = estado_atual
            children.append(novo_estado)
            novo_estado = Estado(estado_atual.canibal_esq - 1, estado_atual.missio_esq - 1, 'direita',
                                  estado_atual.canibal_dir + 1, estado_atual.missio_dir + 1)
            printestado = 'test03'
        ## Um missionário e um canibal cruzam da esquerda pra direita
        elif novo_estado.eh_valido():
            novo_estado.vizinho = estado_atual
            children.append(novo_estado)
            novo_estado = Estado(estado_atual.canibal_esq, estado_atual.missio_esq - 1, 'direita',
                                  estado_atual.canibal_dir, estado_atual.missio_dir + 1)
            printestado = 'test04'
        ## Um missionário cruza da esquerda pra direita
.......
```

**Update based on comments:**
Hi - as the requirement isn't very clear and my knowledge of Portuguese is limited, believe what you are trying to do is to identify the HIGHEST `printestado` for each class/child-class that is created. So, I included that as a variable inside each class and updated it each time the IF statement runs. When the final print is done in `imprime_solucao` function, the individual `printestado` values are printed for each class. The output now has the maximum `testXX` for each class. See if this works....

```
import math

#______________________________________________________________________________
# Missionaries and Cannibals Problem

class Estado():
    def __init__(self, canibal_esq, missio_esq, barco, canibal_dir, missio_dir):
        self.canibal_esq = canibal_esq
        self.missio_esq = missio_esq
        self.barco = barco
        self.canibal_dir = canibal_dir
        self.missio_dir = missio_dir
        self.vizinho = None
        self.printestado = 'teste'

    def objetivo_final(self):
        if self.canibal_esq == 0 and self.missio_esq == 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def eh_valido(self):
        if self.missio_esq >= 0 and self.missio_dir >= 0 \
                   and self.canibal_esq >= 0 and self.canibal_dir >= 0 \
                   and (self.missio_esq == 0 or self.missio_esq >= self.canibal_esq) \
                   and (self.missio_dir == 0 or self.missio_dir >= self.canibal_dir):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.canibal_esq == other.canibal_esq and self.missio_esq == other.missio_esq \
                   and self.barco == other.barco and self.canibal_dir == other.canibal_dir \
                   and self.missio_dir == other.missio_dir

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.canibal_esq, self.missio_esq, self.barco, self.canibal_dir, self.missio_dir))

def successors(estado_atual):
#    global printestado
    children = [];
    if estado_atual.barco == 'esquerda':
        novo_estado = Estado(estado_atual.canibal_esq, estado_atual.missio_esq - 2, 'direita',
                                  estado_atual.canibal_dir, estado_atual.missio_dir + 2)
        estado_atual.printestado = 'test01'
        ## Dois missionários cruzam da esquerda pra direita
        if novo_estado.eh_valido():
            novo_estado.vizinho = estado_atual
            children.append(novo_estado)
            estado_atual.printestado = 'test02'
        novo_estado = Estado(estado_atual.canibal_esq - 2, estado_atual.missio_esq, 'direita',
                                  estado_atual.canibal_dir + 2, estado_atual.missio_dir)
        ## Dois canibais cruzam da esquerda pra direita
        if novo_estado.eh_valido():
            novo_estado.vizinho = estado_atual
            children.append(novo_estado)
            estado_atual.printestado = 'test03'
        novo_estado = Estado(estado_atual.canibal_esq - 1, estado_atual.missio_esq - 1, 'direita',
                                  estado_atual.canibal_dir + 1, estado_atual.missio_dir + 1)
        ## Um missionário e um canibal cruzam da esquerda pra direita
        if novo_estado.eh_valido():
            novo_estado.vizinho = estado_atual
            children.append(novo_estado)
            estado_atual.printestado = 'test04'
        novo_estado = Estado(estado_atual.canibal_esq, estado_atual.missio_esq - 1, 'direita',
                                  estado_atual.canibal_dir, estado_atual.missio_dir + 1)
        ## Um missionário cruza da esquerda pra direita
        if novo_estado.eh_valido():
            novo_estado.vizinho = estado_atual
            children.append(novo_estado)
            estado_atual.printestado = 'test05'
        novo_estado = Estado(estado_atual.canibal_esq - 1, estado_atual.missio_esq, 'direita',
                                  estado_atual.canibal_dir + 1, estado_atual.missio_dir)
        ## Um canibal cruza da esquerda pra direita
        if novo_estado.eh_valido():
            novo_estado.vizinho = estado_atual
            children.append(novo_estado)
    else:
        novo_estado = Estado(estado_atual.canibal_esq, estado_atual.missio_esq + 2, 'esquerda',
                                  estado_atual.canibal_dir, estado_atual.missio_dir - 2)
        printestado = 'test06'
        ## Dois missionários cruzam da direita pra esquerda
        if novo_estado.eh_valido():
            novo_estado.vizinho = estado_atual
            children.append(novo_estado)
            estado_atual.printestado = 'test07'
        novo_estado = Estado(estado_atual.canibal_esq + 2, estado_atual.missio_esq, 'esquerda',
                                  estado_atual.canibal_dir - 2, estado_atual.missio_dir)
        ## Dois canibais cruzam da direita pra esquerda
        if novo_estado.eh_valido():
            novo_estado.vizinho = estado_atual
            children.append(novo_estado)
            estado_atual.printestado = 'test08'
        novo_estado = Estado(estado_atual.canibal_esq + 1, estado_atual.missio_esq + 1, 'esquerda',
                                  estado_atual.canibal_dir - 1, estado_atual.missio_dir - 1)
        ## Um missionário e um canibal cruzam da direita pra esquerda
        if novo_estado.eh_valido():
            novo_estado.vizinho = estado_atual
            children.append(novo_estado)
            estado_atual.printestado = 'test09'
        novo_estado = Estado(estado_atual.canibal_esq, estado_atual.missio_esq + 1, 'esquerda',
                                  estado_atual.canibal_dir, estado_atual.missio_dir - 1)
        ## Um missionário cruza da direita pra esquerda
        if novo_estado.eh_valido():
            novo_estado.vizinho = estado_atual
            children.append(novo_estado)
            estado_atual.printestado = 'test10'
        novo_estado = Estado(estado_atual.canibal_esq + 1, estado_atual.missio_esq, 'esquerda',
                                  estado_atual.canibal_dir - 1, estado_atual.missio_dir)
        ## Um canibal cruza da direita pra esquerda
        if novo_estado.eh_valido():
            novo_estado.vizinho = estado_atual
            children.append(novo_estado)
    return children

def Busca_em_largura():
    estado_inicial = Estado(3,3,'esquerda',0,0)
    if estado_inicial.objetivo_final():
        return estado_inicial
    nao_explorados = list()
    explorados = set()
    nao_explorados.append(estado_inicial)
    while nao_explorados:
        estado = nao_explorados.pop(0)
        if estado.objetivo_final():
            return estado
        explorados.add(estado)
        children = successors(estado)
        for child in children:
            if (child not in explorados) or (child not in nao_explorados):
                nao_explorados.append(child)
    return None

def imprime_solucao(solucao):
        caminho = []
        caminho.append(solucao)
        vizinho = solucao.vizinho
        while vizinho:
            caminho.append(vizinho)
            vizinho = vizinho.vizinho

        for t in range(len(caminho)):
            estado = caminho[len(caminho) - t - 1]
            print("\nCalculando: ")
            print ("(" + str(estado.canibal_esq) + "," + str(estado.missio_esq) \
                              + "," + estado.barco + "," + str(estado.canibal_dir) + "," + \
                              str(estado.missio_dir) + ")")
            print("imprime_solucao printestado -", estado.printestado)

def main():
    solucao = Busca_em_largura()
    print ("Problema dos missionários e canibais: \n")
    print ("Trabalho feito por ")
    print ("Aderbal Calmeto ")
    print ("Guilherme Paiva")
    print ("Legenda: (Canibais à esquerda , Missionários à esquerda")
    print ("Posição do Barco, Canibais à direita , Missionários à direita) \n\n")
    imprime_solucao(solucao)

# if called from the command line, call main()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: is this
if
elif
wlif correct ? which should be the next one ? shouldn't a lot of elifs be enought ?

Comment: That was a typo... they are all ````if/elif```` . Corrected now. If you only have ````if```` the code will check each statement and execute what is inside. At the end, it will always update ````printestado```` to either test5 or test10. So, if you want to run just one of the functions, keep them inside the ````if/elif```` statements and update the variable ```printestado```` inside the if/elif/else statement. In python, the ````tab```` is important, as the code will run the if/else based on which part is indented after the statement

Comment: I'm receiving now the message:

  File "main.py", line 54
    elif novo_estado.eh_valido():
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Paste the whole new code (exactly as you have it, including the tab spacing) in the question. I think it has to do with the spaces/tabs are misaligned, probably on line 53. Also, are you calling the same function ````novo_estado.eh_valido```` 5 times? Any reason for that? The if/elif will run one of the 5 functions, not over and over. I hope that is what you are trying to achieve. Unfortunately, I dont understand the comments either

Comment: I'm edition my post with the entire code @Redox

Comment: The code ran fine. Is it the original code you need modified? Thought you were going to provide the code with error Output : Problema dos missionários e canibais: 

Trabalho feito por 
Aderbal Calmeto 
Guilherme Paiva
Legenda: (Canibais à esquerda , Missionários à esquerda
Posição do Barco, Canibais à direita , Missionários à direita) 



Calculando: 
(3,3,esquerda,0,0)
test10

Calculando: 
(1,3,direita,2,0)
test10

Calculando: 
(2,3,esquerda,1,0)
test10

Calculando: 
(0,3,direita,3,0)
test10

Calculando: 
(1,3,esquerda,2,0)
test10
....

Comment: yeah, that's the full code, it's working perfectly but only this string are taking on me

Comment: when I did what U told, I began having the same issue problem again of SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @Aderbalnevescalmetojunior - Please refer to the updates in the answer section. The output now has the highest ````test0X```` for each class as the ````printestado```` has been added in each class instead of a single global variable